# Weird Safari positioning bug

Tags: css, safari, position, webkit

I have a card in which I display a picture on the left, a title on the right top and some tags on the right bottom. In most browsers it loads like this:

[image]

But when I load the page in Safari, the tags go on top of the title, like this:

[image]

And, what is even stranger, when I hover the "Load more" button, the page returns to its normal state, as it should be from the beginning (I thought that box-shadows didn't affect DOM positioning).

Facts:

1. In its inactive state, the "Load more" button has a 4px box-shadow, but when it's hovered the box-shadow is none.
2. When I tried to remove the box-shadow of the button completely, Safari rendered it the wrong way and it stayed the same, even when I hovered the button.
3. The tags are wrapped in an absolute-positioned DIV, with bottom: 0.
4. The wrapper of all items (big white round-cornered rectangle) is a flexbox.
5. The title and the tags DIV are wrapped in a relative-positioned DIV.

How can I fix this issue?

**EDIT**

Here is the bit of my code which controls this card:

```css
*{
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
 background-color: rgb(239,239,239);
 margin: 0;
}

.grid{
 width: 100%;
 padding: 10px;
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: flex;
 -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
 -webkit-box-direction: normal;
 flex-direction: column;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');

.item{
 background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 padding: 20px;
 border: 4px solid rgb(232,232,232);
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: flex;
 -webkit-box-flex: 1;
 flex: 1 1 auto;
 margin: 10px;

 -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
         border-radius: 30px;
}

.item .info{
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
}

.item .photo{
 display: inline-block;
 height: 10em;
 width: 10em;
 margin-right: 2.5em;

 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
         border-radius: 50%;

 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
         box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.item h1{
 font-weight: 700;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 margin: 0;
}

.item .tags{
 bottom: 0;
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
}

.item .tag{
 background-color: rgb(236,237,240);
 color: rgb(153,153,153);
 text-transform: uppercase;
 padding: 0.6em 2em;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0.5em 0.5em 0 0.5em;
 max-width: 14em;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 white-space: nowrap;
 -webkit-border-radius: 1.5em;
    -moz-border-radius: 1.5em;
      border-radius: 1.5em;
}

.item .tag.unloaded{
 background-color: rgb(160,160,160);
 color: rgb(255,255,255);

 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
         box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.item .tag:first-child{
 margin-left: 0;
}

.item .tag:last-child{
 margin-right:0;
}

.item .tag.unloaded:hover{
 background-color: rgb(100,100,100);
 color: rgb(255,255,255);
 -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
         box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
  <title>FlickList</title>

  <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/grid.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/components/item.css" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
 <body>
  <section class="grid">
   <div class="item">
    <img class="photo" src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/26559/pexels-photo-26559.jpg" alt="Forest"/>
    <div class="info">
     <h1>Forest</h1>
     <div class="tags">
      <span class="tag unloaded">Load more</span>
      <span class="tag">Test</span>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </section>
 </body>
</html>
```

**.item** is the card itself (the big white round-cornered rectangle)

**.item .info** is the relative-positioned wrapper around the title and the tags

**.item .tags** is the tags wrapper

**.item .tag.unloaded** is the style of the "Load more" button

Comment: Safari WIndows/Mac?

Comment: @makshh Windows, I haven't tested in a Mac yet

Comment: I think you should add `-webkit-` prefixes to all flex related properties.

Comment: If Safari on Windows is broken, it's likely because it hasn't been updated since version 5.1.7 in 2012. That said, it's probably possible to make it work (possibly by using whatever flexbox properties it expects).

Comment: @makshh I did add the prefix

Comment: @TimMedora my version is 5.1.4 and I've used all the flex related properties it allows me to (and of course only the ones I needed)